# Datastore search via composite index does not work

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  I have a composite index

```
- kind: Products
  ancestor: yes
  properties:
  - name: handle
```

From console:

[image]

when I do filter I do not get any results even though that entity exists.

[image]

Comment: Do you have new values after creating this index? I'm asking because adding a property to an index [does not affect entities added previously](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/indexes#unindexed-properties), and it may explain why you are not getting any results.

Comment: ahh... that can explain.  so basically I need to reload data and removed `noindex` tag for that field.  I guess, I made the wrong assumption.  I thought if I write data with `noindex` tag I can later create a composite index to target that field. Gladly it affected only one customer.

Comment: Yes, you can reload the data. As mentioned, any change on the index will not affect previous entities. If you don't mind, I will post this bit as an answer, and you can approve it (if you wish to, of course).

Comment: Yes, please do that.  I will check mark as answered.

Comment: Already done! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a property to an index [does not affect entities added previously](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/indexes#unindexed-properties). This explains why you can't get any results.

You can 'reload' the data, and remove the `noindex` tag for that field.

Comment: No problem @Askar :)